# How to set your unique key number of the field Id of the table when creating the code-first database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a problem when creating the table at the moment when I want to set my Id key, the table assigns its code in order, I need to make it in the format "20190123" for later search.

How can I set my unique key in the table?

Is it necessary to remove the auto-increment for this?

```
public class RentalDbInitializer: DropCreateDatabaseAlways<RentalContext>
{
        protected override void Seed(RentalContext context)
        {
            context.People.Add(new Person { Id = 1, FirstName = "Ivan", LastName = "Ivanov" });

            context.RentalDates.Add(new RentalDate { Id = int.Parse(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString("yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)), DateTimeRental = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2) });

            context.Rentals.Add(new Rental { PersonId = 1, RentalDateId = int.Parse(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString("yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)), Hours = 10, Cost = 200 });

            base.Seed(context);
        }
}
```

Comment: What error are you seeing? Also, can you give the definitions of your classes.

Comment: Unique key and Primary key - are two different things and often both needed. PK is for your DB to function. UK is for you to function. Don't combine them, and you will be alright.

Comment: You should use a Date field for this, not an integer, and a generated PK that's meaningless wrt your business logic.